# ArgumentException in ParameterizedThreadStart with Graphics C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, graphics

I need to pass Graphics object into thread start method via parameters, however it for some reason makes it invalid and throws ArgumentException : Parameter is not valid.

Simplified view of a problem:

```
private void Canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Start(e.Graphics);
}

public void Start(Graphics g)
{
    new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Render)).Start(g);
}

private void Render(object g)
{
    ((Graphics)g).DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 50, 50, 50, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening becuase Graphics object obtained in the event handler is temporary and becomes disposed when the background thread executes.

Instead, you should pass the control to the background thread.

Also, instead of a background thread, you should use the `System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperationManager` to be on the safe side:

```
private void Canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Start((Control)sender);
}

public void Start(Control uiControl)
{
    AsyncOperation asyncOperation = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);
    asyncOperation.Post(Render, uiControl);
}

private void Render(object g)
{
    ((Control)g).CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 50, 50, 50, 50);
}
```